# column headings in SSRS report exported as csv

Tags: csv, reporting-services

We have a client that wants a SSRS report sent as a .csv but uses pipe delimitation.  In the first line of the file they want what appears as column headings like this.

```
LSP Partner|Customer Code|Customer Name|Address 1|Address 2|Postal Code|VAT Number |City|Customer Type|Customer Group|Credit Limit|Email|Payment Term Code|Payment Term Description|Payment Term Days|Country Code|Country Name|Customer Currency|Customer Branch Code|Customer Branch Name|Customer Risk Category|Customer Creation Timestamp
```

When you export from SSRS as csv and open it in Excel uses the cell name as cell A1.  I found a way to remove that but it will not pick up the column headings.

Comment: CSV's don't have cells, open it in a text editor. If you open it in excel it will attempt to parse it. If it looks wrong via a text editor then update your question and explain what is wrong. At the moment it's not clear

Comment: I have updated the problem as suggested by Alan.  Thank you

Comment: Still not clear. To your question add a sample of the CSV with header and first 2-3 rows. Then  show (**not as image**) how it is presented in Excel.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I do not see a way to upload an example.  The report that we need will be imported into a SAP system.  The requirements is the 1st row be what would look like column headings in an Excel file.  The second + rows would be the data.  Everything is pipe delimited.